# Example: How To Programmatically Fill An Android Spinner from an Array in MonoDroid / C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-spinner

I started fiddling around with MonoDroid this week. Not that I don't appreciate Java, but I spend most of my time in either Visual Studio / C# or Delphi, and I'd rather pull my fingernails out than learn YET ANOTHER IDE and YET ANOTHER editor in order to use Eclipse.

I adapted this code to C# from Java, for situations where it's easier to populate my spinner programmatically in C# code rather than in the AXML. Perhaps some of you may find it helpful.

Create a generic Spinner In Your Activity's axml:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/spinner_prompt"
/>
```

Build your array of string somewhere appropriate:

```
public static readonly string[] refresh_ratesS = {"10 seconds","20 seconds","30 seconds","60 seconds","5 minutes"};
```

I prefer to instantiate objects in the Activity's public class so that I only have to identify them once:

```
public class ActivityChooseRefreshRate :Activity {
    Spinner         jb_spinner;
```

In the Activity's OnCreate function assign your array to the spinner:

```
     //identify the spinner
jb_spinner      =   FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner);
     //create the handler for when the user selects something
jb_spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<ItemEventArgs> (jb_spinner_ItemSelected);
    //assign your array to an ArrayAdapter
ArrayAdapter<string>  spinnerArrayAdapter   =   new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem,refresh_ratesS);
      //Use the ArrayAdapter you've set up to populate your spinner
spinnerArrayAdapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
jb_spinner.Adapter      =   spinnerArrayAdapter;
   //optionally pre-set jb_spinner to an index
jb_spinner.SetSelection(2);
```

Lastly, code the jb_spinner_ItemSelected handler so that something happens when the user makes a selection:

```
private void jb_spinner_ItemSelected (object sender, ItemEventArgs e){
    Spinner spinner     = (Spinner)sender;
         //do something here, such as raise a Toast
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Index="+e.Position.ToString(),ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but we need tutorials like this to be just like any other question. Could you change the question to ask something specific that this addresses, and move the tutorial into an answer? After that, feel free to accept your own answer. Otherwise, this will likely be closed in the near future.